# Webpack command in node brings /config/webpack/development.js not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, babeljs

I have written my webpack.config file but when i run webpack from terminal i get back an error saying:

> **ERROR:** Webpack config
>   /home/likono/learn/yak-yik/config/webpack/development.js not found,
>   please run 'bundle exec rails webpacker:install' to install webpacker
>   with default configs or add the missing config file for your custom
>   environment.

I have also installed webpack globally.
**Here is my webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yak-yik",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.4",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: "webpack": "^3.8.1"

Comment: Okay cool. May you please upload you `package.json`

Comment: Okay i have added it

Comment: Thanks, please excuse the copious amounts of question, but how are you running this command in the terminal?

Comment: no problem. I was trying to run webpack just from the terminal first before putting it to the scripts in package.json. So right now i just type webpack from the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of issues with the configuration above. According to [Babel](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed), It's no longer allowed to omit the `-loader` suffix when using `loaders`. You need to specify `babel-loader` instead of `babel`. Also `babel-preset-es2015` is deprecated, it is recommended to rather use `babel-preset-env`. I could not get to reproduce your error though (I got slightly different ones), but got my webpack to bundle the file on my side by altering the `loader` from `babel` to `babel-loader` and, and `presets`, changed `es2015` to `env` in `webpack.config.js` like so:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules)/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'env']
  }
}
```

I also changed the `package.json` file to use `babel-preset-env` instead of `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"`.

**package.js**

```
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
```

Please give this a try and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot it has. I think i will have to go through the docs to learn more about babel and webpack

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please consider ticking the answer as an accepted one.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks you so much.. I have